# Setting up a complex Grid Layout while respecting image aspect ratio and paddings

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I need to build a pretty complex grid layout: [image]

Basically the grid is not too hard to get right, what makes it difficult though is to respect the following rules:

- Keep image aspect ratio (square)
- Keep equal margin between all grid items (shown in green)
- Have left borders shown as in the image attached

That comes with another difficulty:

- Blog Article Excerpts must (!) have various lengths

I already have a solution using Flexbox. Therefore I set up three columns and the client can choose which blogpost to show at what position and in what column.
They have not complained about it, I still feel this should be more convenient.

Above that it get's pretty complex for smaller screens and devices as I had to ditch the layout and use JavaScript to create a new array to achieve (almost) the same article order as on desktop screens.

I just tried setting it up using CSS Grid but again with all the undefined things (text length) I could not find a solution to respect either the aspect ratio or the grid item margins.

Is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: Flexbox is probably the best way, but you could also try using tables with colspan and rowspan. Although its really annoying to try and style a table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got. But making the grid adaptive is quite difficult

https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/qBWoWmx

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  max-width: 1340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  grid-row: span 7;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.item--big {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 12;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.item__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__title {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item__desc {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.item__link {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item--big">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item--big">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item--big">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item--big">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="item__img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="536" height="354" alt="Item image">
    </figure>
    <h3 class="item__title">Item title</h3>
    <p class="item__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, consectetur obcaecati</p>
    <a class="item__link" href="">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```